# How is this bit mask merge derived to what author suggets?

Tags: bitmask

From the following Sean Anderson's page:
http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#MaskedMerge

He says that result of [ (a & ~mask) | (b & mask) ]
can be written as [ a ^ ((a ^ b) & mask); ]

From the problem statement, it is intuitive to do  [ (a & ~mask) | (b & mask) ]. But how do I derive the later expression from the first one? Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, `& bits` means "take these bits", and `^ bits` means "flip these bits".

The original expression, `(a & ~mask) | (b & mask)`, means "take bits from `b` selected by the mask, and take the rest of the bits from `a`".

Let's start with `(b & mask)` — the bits of `b` selected by the mask.

`a ^ (b & mask)` would flip some bits of that — namely, the 1-bits of `a`.  Which is almost correct.  However, we don't actually want to flip the 1-bits of `a` that were selected by the mask.  To correct those bits in the positions where both `a` and `mask` are 1, we flip them again: `a ^ ((a ^ b) & mask)`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. As I see it, `a ^ ((a ^ b) & mask)` will be same as `a ^ (a ^ (b & mask))`.

Comment: No, `a ^ (a ^ (b & mask))` is the same as `(a ^ a) ^ (b & mask)`, which is `0 ^ (b & mask)`, or just `(b & mask)`.